Regex to split out json objects and key values from field in Snowflake table
I have json objects inside a VARCHAR field in Snowflake and would like to extract each resource and the actions that can be applied in another column ideally represented like key and values in delimited list something like
e.g.
["arn:aws:s3::testfiles"="s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],["arn:aws:s3:::testfiles/"="s3:ListAllMyBuckets"]

or multiple columns for each resource and action group with work too but this would need to be dynamic as there can be multiple and varying number of resources and actions in each json object.
My query is how can I do this in Snowflake?
I was thinking I could convert the field text into a list of json objects and then parse the json and extract just the fields I'm interested in but I can't get the regex to remove just the json object names so it becomes valid json.  I have tried to use a wildcard as shown below but it removes too much and think it is to do with the curly brace but have tried to escape it and still does not work as I would expect it too.
REGEXP_REPLACE(merged_json,'S3_.*{', '{')

Thanks for any help.
Example of field value.  I've highlighted in bold the values I'm trying to replace to convert it into list of json objects.  Each one is prefixed with S3_

S3_TestFile{"Version": "2024-01-17","Statement": [{"Sid":
"1234","Effect": "Allow","Action": ["s3:"],"Resource":
["arn:aws:s3::testfiles"]},{"Sid": "AllowUserAction","Effect":
"Allow","Action":
["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion","s3:DeleteObject","s3:DeleteObjectVersion","s3:GetObjectAcl"],"Resource":
"arn:aws:s3:::testfiles/"}]} S3_ProdAccess{"Version":
"2024-01-17","Statement": [{"Sid": "AllowGroupToList","Action":
["s3:ListAllMyBuckets","s3:GetBucketLocation"],"Effect":
"Allow","Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::"]},{"Sid":
"AllowListingOfTheBucket","Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],"Effect":
"Allow","Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::2020files"],"Condition":
{"StringEquals": {"s3:prefix": [""],"s3:delimiter": ["/"]}}},{"Sid":
"AllowListBucket","Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],"Effect":
"Allow","Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::2020files"],"Condition":
{"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": [""]}}},{"Sid":
"AllowUserWithinBucket","Effect": "Allow","Action":
["s3:*"],"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::2020files/**"}]}S3_Policy_End


Does 'S3_.*?{'? work?

Do you have a clean sample of the input? The one with the bold S3_TestFile, S3_ProdAccess, S3_Policy_End doesn't look like json

'S3_.*?{' does appear to remove the text in bold either.  Seems to remove everything up to the word "Effect"

I'm hoping to remove the ones in bold and change it into json list of objects so I can parse it which might help with getting the information I need but can't find a way to remove the words in bold

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257426/pq-solution-json

Thanks @horseyride thats helped me progress me alot closer to my target.  Thanks alot for the help
